# How to conditionally run functions based on input

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to allow the user to specify which functions to run and the order in which they are run.

The user's choice ends up as an array; `['option1', 'option4', 'option2']`

Each option relates to a specific function and each function has a callback.

How can I run `handleOption1` first, wait for the callback then run `handleOption4`, wait for the callback then run `handleOption2` (given the input above)?

Comment: Can you include the functions at the Question?

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried? If you show your code I'm sure we can help

Comment: I didn't have any code to show for this section as I didn't know where to start. The answer below seems to have worked as expected (with a couple of tweaks). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating through asynchronous functions is super easy with async await. An example could be :

```
const handlers = [
  {
    key: 'option1',
    func: async () => { ... do asyn stuff }
  },
  {
    key: 'option2',
    func: async () => { ... do asyn stuff }
  },
  {
    key: 'option3',
    func: async () => { ... do asyn stuff }
  }
];

const exec = async options => {
  for(const opt of options) {
    const currentHandler = handlers.find(h => h.key == option);
    await currentHandler();
  };
}

// Get user options, execute program

exec(options)
.catch(console.error);
```